# How do you shutdown or reset a Owin Self Host

Tags: c#, signalr, owin

I am hosting a  signalr  app using Owin self host.

```
public class Startup1
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

I have a class that I use to start the host.

```
public class SignalRHost
{
    public void start()
    {
        WebApp.Start("http://localhost:8081");
    }
    public void start(string urlAndPort)
    {
        WebApp.Start(urlAndPort);
    }
}
```

It starts  but how should I shutdown the host when I need to. I can't find anything here at the moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OWIN Stop Server\Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562192/owin-stop-server-service)

Answer (score 2):

`Start` method returns an `IDisposable`, if you keep it around and call `Dispose` on it when you need to restart then you should be good.

I remember about some issue with SignalR internals while doing this, but that was a long time ago so I guess it is solved now.

Also, try not to restart it when SignalR is actually doing anything, like serving hub's methods.